# Bash history keyboard shortcut for !*

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

In Bash, there are some handy operators to repeat parts of the last command:

- `!^` expands to the first argument of the previous command, e.g.,

  ```
  $ echo one "two three"
  one two three
  $ echo !^
  echo one
  one
  ```
- `!$` expands to the last argument of the previous command, e.g.,

  ```
  $ echo one "two three"
  one two three
  $ echo !$
  echo "two three"
  two three
  ```
- `!*` expands to all arguments of the previous command, e.g.,

  ```
  $ echo one "two three"
  one two three
  $ echo !*
  echo one "two three"
  one two three
  ```

(As far as I understand, these are syntactic sugar for `!!:^`, `!!:$` and `!!:*` respectively, where `!!` is an event designator that expands to the previous command, and `^`, `$` and `*` are word designators, see the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) or `man bash`.)

These are often quite handy. But it gets even cooler with keyboard shortcuts:

- When you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>, the last argument of the previous command is inserted in the current command, similarly as if you had written `!$` at that point.
- It is also possible to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to insert the first argument of the previous command, as if you had written `!^` at that point.

(See the [GNU Readline Library](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html) or `info readline`.)

I tend to prefer the keyboard shortcuts over Bash's history operators, because I can see what I'm inserting before I actually execute the command. However, there does not seem to be a shortcut that enables me to insert all the words of the previous command, i.e., one that does `!*`'s job. At least I could not find it.

Is there such a shortcut? If not, is it possible to configure the readline library to add one, and how?

Comment: AFAIK, keyboard shortcuts are handled by the terminal emulator. So I suppose you're using gnome-terminal?

Comment: In `zsh`, if you type `echo !*` and then press TAB, you have the desired effect. In general, TAB while in readline will expand all the expandable. Very handy; probably bash will have some configuration to the same effect? @Seth, I think this is the readline into bash, not the terminal emulator - not sure though.

Comment: @Seth No, the shortcuts from the Q are handled by bash. You can serch for *'Commands for Manipulating the History'* in `man bash` (somewhere at the line 3030)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Oh interesting! I didn't know that. My bad for bad assumptions.

Comment: @Seth Actually I'm using urxvt (not gnome-terminal), but as Rmano and Radu already said, this concerns readline in bash, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Rmano About `zsh`, this is cool and interesting, but I grew quite accustomed to bash. I would be curious if there is a bash solution. :)

Comment: `\e.` and `\e_` are mapped to readline function `yank-last-arg` and `\e\C-y` is mapped to `yank-nth-arg`. Sadly there seems to be no (single) command that adds multiple previous arguments at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the output of the following command:

```
bind -l
```

or better to:

```
bind -l | grep arg
```

you can see that doesn't exist any readline function for all arguments like is, for example, `yank-last-arg` for last argument - which can insert last argument to the previous command (the last word of the previous history entry). So, if such a function doesn't exists, most probably doesn't exist a shortcut to accomplish what you wish.

Let's try to crate one approached to your request...

First, look for example at the output of the following command:

```
bind -p | grep yank-nth-arg
```

The output is:

```
"\e\C-y": yank-nth-arg
```

and can be translated as follow: `yank-nth-arg` (which insert the first argument to the previous command - with an argument n, insert the nth argument from the previous command) is bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

In the same way can be interpreted any line from the output of `bind -p` command.

Now play attention at the following scenarios:

- If you set the following binding:

  ```
  bind '"\ea": "\e2\e."'
  ```

  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will be mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> which is mapped to insert the second argument of the previous command. So, after when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the *second* argument of the previous command is inserted in the current command.
- If you set:

  ```
  bind '"\ea": "\e1\e. \e2\e."'
  ```

  After when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the *first two* arguments of the previous command is inserted in the current command. If the number of the arguments from the previous command is maximum 2, of course *all* of the previous command is inserted in the current command.
- If you set:

  ```
  bind '"\ea": "\e1\e. \e2\e. \e3\e."'
  ```

  After when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the *first three* arguments of the previous command is inserted in the current command. If the number of the arguments from the previous command is maximum 3 (as in your case), of course *all* of the previous command is inserted in the current command.
- And so on.

For first 10 arguments, you can use:

```
bind '"\ea": "\e1\e. \e2\e. \e3\e. \e4\e. \e5\e. \e6\e. \e7\e. \e8\e. \e9\e. \e1\e0\e."'
```

And I think that this is long enough as far as I don't use too often commands with so many arguments.

To make it persistent, add the following line line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\ea": "\e1\e. \e2\e. \e3\e. \e4\e. \e5\e. \e6\e. \e7\e. \e8\e. \e9\e. \e1\e0\e."
```

In this example I chose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to insert all arguments (if the number of arguments is not greater than 10) of the previous command, but you can chose any other combination you with by replacing in the previous command the `\ea` string.

Resources:

- [Commands For Manipulating The History](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#IDX82)
- `help -m bind`
- [BASH - How to use arguments from previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/bash-how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command)