# Deleting input back to the last forward slash

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

I will very often be flitting between several files on a server. I will run the following example commands in sequence:

```
nano /web/site/path/to/file
/web/site/script.py
nano /web/site/path/to/anotherFile
nano /web/site/path/to/yetAnotherFile
/web/site/script.py
nano /web/site/path/to/etc
```

To go from one `nano` command to the next I currently press <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to replace the last segment of the path. The problem with this is I'm really, *really* lazy.

Is there a keyboard shortcut (or Bashism) that can either:

- Get replaced by the last path used (with an extra bit on the end)
- Delete in the current line (eg after pressing <kbd>Up</kbd>) back to the last `/`

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I think for the first part you can use `alt`+`.`?

Comment: @Sparhawk `Alt + .` is used for [something else](http://askubuntu.com/q/439116/147044).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Yeah, perhaps I misunderstand the question. I thought "Get replaced by the last path used (with an extra bit on the end)" meant what `alt`+`.` does.

Comment: @Sparhawk Again, one of those shortcuts that's really useful about once a month that I just don't seem able to commit to memory. In combination with alt-backspace, it's pretty handy for running similar files through different commands.

Comment: @Oli I tend to use it a fair bit, but I always forget how to [move the other way](https://superuser.com/questions/593857/how-can-you-reverse-the-direction-of-alt-period-in-bash)!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you're looking for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> shortcut.

After pressing <kbd>Up</kbd> this should delete back to the previous `/` or `space` character.

Comment: NOW I AM UNSTOPPABLE! (Edit: I swear I learn and forgot this shortcut at least ten times a year)

Comment: What should this do? On my terminal it doesn't seem to do anything different than plain `backspace`.

Comment: @Bakuriu This shortcut should be the default one. If you want to find out what it's mapped to on your system run `bind -P | grep '^backward-kill-word'`

Comment: @Bakuriu Same here, I'm on Mac.

Comment: note `Alt+Ctrl+h` or `^[+h` will also work

Answer (score 10):

To detect the readline binding that kill a word backward as you wish you can use the following command in your terminal:

```
bind -p | awk '/kill/ && /word/ && /backward/'
```

In a default Ubuntu installation, the output could be:

```
"\e\C-h": backward-kill-word
# shell-backward-kill-word (not bound)
```

The second line seems without importance  at this point, so let's try to see what means first line. From what I understand, the [`backward-kill-word`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-backward_002dkill_002dword-_0028M_002dDEL_0029) readline function which in fact delete all characters untill the previous special character (`/`, `;`, `,` etc.) is bound to the `\e\C-h` key sequence. Now, in this sequence `\e` [represents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, `\C` - the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, and `\C-h` stands for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> which [is equivalent in this case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH) with <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key.

So, you are searching for **<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>** keyboard shortcut which is equivalent with **<kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>** and which, *because of xterm's behaviour that make <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to act as a meta character and meta characters are converted into a two-character sequence with the character itself preceded by <kbd>Esc</kbd> (see `man xterm`)*, is equivalent with **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>**.

Now, if you don't like it and you continue to forget it, you can use the following command to create a new shortcut, let say <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, for your purpose:

```
bind '"\ew": backward-kill-word'
```

To make this new shortcut persistent all the time for all commands that uses readline, add the following line line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\ew": backward-kill-word
```

See `help -m bind | sensible-pager` for more info.

Comment: Good answer. More commonly you'd enclose the whole setting in single quotes with the bind command; `bind '"\ew": backward-kill-word'`, but that's nitpicking. And it may be worth mentioning that you can also put `"\ew": backward-kill-word` in `~/.inputrc`, in which case other commands that use readline will also have that binding, e.g. if you enable readline in the python interactive shell, that binding will also apply there.

Comment: @geirha Yes, [I am aware](http://askubuntu.com/a/439158/147044) what you said, but I thought that the OP knows how to manage this. Anyway, now I realize that my answer is not so useful for the OP (he just wanted to remember the shortcut), but I hope to be useful for other users of this site and for this I edited my answer by adding your observation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Another key combination is:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>

```
Alt + B     Move cursor backward one word on the current line    
Ctrl + K    Clear the line after the cursor
```

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

This removes last word without deleting special char between words.