# Deleting input forward to the next space

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

When in terminal I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to delete a whole word or IP (`.` is separator for each octet) when going leftward of prompt. However, if I try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to go rightward of prompt, terminal recognizes "." in IP for a separator and deletes only one chunk, until the `.` out of the whole IP.

How can I adjust that so terminal recognizes only blank spaces for separator of word or even better to have another shortcut for different separators: `.`, `=`, `,`, etc?

It is very similar with maneuvering  in terminal with Ctrl+Arrows (left and right) and behavior is similar based on what is set for word separator.

I read that Emacs editor sits behind what terminal uses to have those shortcuts but I could not get to twink it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use the following command in your terminal:

```
bind '"\ew": vi-forward-bigword'
```

to create a new shortcut-key - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> in this case - which will move the prompt forward to the end of the current or next word. In this case words (*bigwords*) are composed of letters, digits and special characters like ".".

Now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> to accomplish what you wish.

See some more info in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/539495/147044).

---

Moreover, after I viewed [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13978131/2353900), I understood the following:

> With `bind`, you can bind keys to do one of three things, ***but no
>   combination of them***:
>
> - Execute a readline command:      `bind '"key": command'`
> - Execute a series of keystrokes: `bind '"key":"keystrokes"'`
> - Execute a shell command: `bind -x '"key": shell-command'`

So, now, if you want to combine those two keystrokes (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>) in a new one, you will need to bind a new keystroke (in my example <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>) to execute the previous keystrokes as follow:

```
bind '"\eq": "\ew \C-w"'
```

Finally, to make these changes permanently, all you have to do is to add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc` file (if you don't have it, then create it):

```
"\ew": vi-forward-bigword
"\eq": "\ew \C-w"
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your suggestion. I will try it and let you know how it works. What would be command for creating shortcut moving back and forth to the next black space?

Comment: Hi, the command: bind '"\ew": vi-forward-bigword' ran in terminal, but then shortcuts did not work as you said. I must be missing something here. Could you help to find solution for that? Thanks

Comment: @Lacho Try to add this line: `"\ew": vi-forward-bigword` to your `~/.inputrc` file, then restart your session.

Comment: When added that, alt+w still does not work, and ctrl + left and right error does not work any more. Terminal outputs ;5D and ;5C when those are used to move from word to word... Strange. Where do you read about those features?

Comment: @Lacho In this case I'm almost sure, if yu are using bash, that you made a mismatch. Check the quotes for example to be exactly as I wrote them...

Comment: Hi @Radu Rădeanu, so I was able to get going your suggestion and it works. However, it is not in that much help... I can use "END" button in order to accomplish what you have suggested. Do you think we can construct a command (eg. alt+w ) that will delete a word forward of prompts to the next blank space? let's say we have: "I have this string: 111.222.333 of numbers" and the cursor is in front of 111.222.333, so by pressing alt + w to delete just 111.222.333? It works if I have the cursor behind 111.222.333 and pressing ctr+w?  Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried this: bind `'"\ew": forward-kill-bigword'` but didn't work. Also, I am not exactly sure what they talk about in here: `help -m bind | sensible-pager `

Comment: @Lacho That because doesn't exist such a command (readline function): `forward-kill-bigword`. See my new edits at the answer and if your problem is solved, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi again @Radu Rădeanu, So on the new version of Ubuntu that works but on older version 10.xx, it does not work. I get 5D and ;5C when those are used to move from word to word..., as I have stated above. What could be the reason behind it? could you point me out as to what to check to see if I am going to be able to set new keyboard shortcut. When run `help -m bind | sensible-pager` I get output that I should be able to set it. Thanks

Comment: So, your question is about Ubuntu 10.xx? Sorry, but if it so, your question it is not on topic in this case. Please see [what topics can you ask about here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Radu Rădeanu this command : `bind '"\eq":shell-kill-word'` works for me. Earlier version of Ubuntu does not recongnize `vi-forward-bigword`. Do you know how to bind a shortcut to `C-q`. I tried and it didn't work...