# How do I make Ctrl-arrow skip over dots and dashes

Tags: command-line, bash

on the commandline

How do I get my cursor to jump from `a` to `z` directly if I use `ctrl-rightarrow` for the word `a-very-long-resource-name.12.45-ending-in-z`

Comment: I don't think it's possible to modify the behavior of the readline `forward-word` directly - see for example [What are the readline word separators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78992/65304), however you might try binding `vi-forward-bigword` to something instead - see for example [Deleting input forward to the next space](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577433/deleting-input-forward-to-the-next-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [the following actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bindable-Readline-Commands):

> `shell-forward-word` (`M-C-f`)
>
> Move forward to the end of the next word. Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.
>
> `shell-backward-word` (`M-C-b`)
>
> Move back to the start of the current or previous word. Words are delimited by non-quoted shell metacharacters.

Their default keybindings are <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>b</kbd>, and you can use either <kbd>Alt</kbd> as Meta, or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>/<kbd>b</kbd>. If those shortcuts do what you want, then you can rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to them. But to do that, you'd need first find out what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> means in the terminal. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>. This will result in some characters showing up in the terminal (in my case that's `^[[1;5D` for <kbd>←</kbd> and `^[[1;5C` for <kbd>→</kbd>). Then to bind these key codes, I can use the following command (`^[` becomes `\e`):

```
bind '"\e[1;5C": shell-forward-word'
bind '"\e[1;5D": shell-backward-word'
```